# Multi-part Equation needing to Auto Calculate = Failure

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, appery.io

Good Evening All,
I am stuck,
I have 1 equation that need's to auto-calculate, but I cannot work out how to get that to work (code below). Basically, the user has two pop up's, they make their selection & then it should auto-calculate, then the user make's 1 more entry and it should auto-calculate again (I hope that make's sense?!).

I have tried (using Appery.io who are absolutely useless!! << not my choice, client's choice!!) BLUR, KEYUP & VALUE CHANGE for the auto-calculation. I am also stuck to JavaScript only.

Code:

```
var rc1FrontMM = Number(Apperyio("rc1FrontMM").val());
var rc1RearMM = Number(Apperyio("rc1RearMM").val());
var rc1TyreRatio1 = Number(Apperyio("rc1TyreRatio1").val());
var rc1TyreRatio2 = Number(Apperyio("rc1TyreRatio2").val());

var rc1TyreRatio1 = (rc1RearMM / rc1FrontMM);
var rc1TyreRatio2 = (rc1RearMM / rc1FrontMM);

Apperyio('rc1TyreRatio1').val(rc1TyreRatio1.toFixed(2) + "%");
Apperyio('rc1TyreRatio2').val(rc1TyreRatio2.toFixed(2) + "%");
```

This is part 1 for the auto-calculation, if I can solve this, I can solve the rest. Screenshot's of the app below, thank you all.

[image: The layout]

[image: The final choice & no auto-calculation]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-calculate every time user inputs new value to any of your input components, then:

- wrap your code with a function and add it to js file, that should be created in the project
- add a key up event handler for each of your input components

Also try to add some if statements to check if all values are Numbers and all of them defined.

I hope that helps.